# Applescript: customizing the UI button options

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash

I’m trying to use Applescript to produce a simple UI menu, but instead of the default “OK”, and “Cancel” I would like to change the behavior to the following:

[Dialog title at top]

“Cancel” changed to “Exit”
“OK” changed to “Run”

Have the “Run” button execute a BASH script in the current folder.

Code thus far (not much):

`osascript -e 'display dialog "Press RUN to execute the Optimizer" with title "Optimizer"'`

Comment: The scripting dictionary for **StandardAdditions** can be opened in the **Script Editor** - it will show you the options and results for the various dialog commands.

Comment: Thank you but this seems to be helpful for calling apps, but not shell scripts.

Comment: Yes, scripting dictionaries are where the various application scripting terms are defined, but they were also used for additions to AppleScript.  The **StandardAdditions** scripting dictionary is where you will find information about Apple’s additional AppleScript commands, such as `display dialog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a dialogue with osascript, try:

```
echo "set ddr to display dialog \"Press RUN to execute the Optimizer\" with title \"Optimizer\" buttons {\"Exit\", \"Run\"} default button \"Run\" cancel button \"Exit\"" | osascript -
```

That runs the following applescript command from the shell:

```
set ddr to display dialog "Press RUN to execute the Optimizer" ¬
with title "Optimizer" buttons {"Exit", "Run"} ¬
default button "Run" cancel button "Exit"
```

Note that in the `echo`, the " are escaped but the {} are not. Depending upon your approach, this may change.

See more on `display dialog` in the [ASLG here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW12)

Based on the ASLG example and your description above, to get a dialogue-driven shell script to run, try this:

```
echo "set uc to false
try
set ddr to display dialog \"Press RUN to execute the Optimizer\" with title \"Optimizer\" buttons {\"Exit\", \"Run\"} default button \"Run\" cancel button \"Exit\"
on error number -128                                      
set uc to true
end try
if uc then
display alert \"User cancelled\"
else if button returned of ddr is \"Run\" then
do shell script \"pwd\"
end if" | osascript -
```

Per `man osascript`, an alternative approach would be to save the applescript code as a text file (or compiled applescript) somewhere and run osascript on it, like so:

```
% osascript as_code.txt

% osascript as_code.scpt
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Glad it works for you. My pleasure.